# Motivation for working with augmented objects in homological or higher algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff

I would like to understand if there is deeper reason/motivation behind
augmentations in homological algebra. Recall classically in homology
if there is a complex of free $R$-modules ($R commutative unitary ring)

$$ ... \xrightarrow{\partial_{n+1}} C_n \xrightarrow{\partial_{n}} C_{n-1}
\xrightarrow{\partial_{n-1}} ... \xrightarrow{\partial_{2}} C_1
\xrightarrow{\partial_{1}} C_0 \to 0  $$

then it can be turned to **augmented** chain complex by extending the right part
to

$$ ... \xrightarrow{\partial_{2}} C_1
\xrightarrow{\partial_{1}} C_0 \xrightarrow{\epsilon} R \to 0  $$

where $\epsilon(\sum_i a_i \sigma_i)):= \sum_i a_i \in R$

such that the $0$-th cohomology $H^0$ of the original complex and
of the augmented complex $H^0_a$ are related by $H^0= H^0_a \oplus R$.

Fine, but the question is if there is any deeper philosophical reason
behind using augmentations or is it just a historical leftover (I'm not sure who introduced this concept first. Eilenberg?) Moreover was it to pass to augmented objects just a "matter of taste" or was there some deeper mathematical reason behind?

(Maybe it's in *certain sence* more flexible for certain generalization directions. For example to work in some situations more "uniformly", I don't know, that's just a guess) Obviously there is no information
gain/loss when passing to augmented objects. Are there nevertheless any advantages
to pass to them? For example does this concept maybe provide better
structural /functorial compatibilities or say "more natural framework" when working in more general setting (eg simplicial objects in higher categoy theory)?

Another guess: does augmentation play some interesting interpretation or give some interesting viewpoint in context of classical Dold-Kan corresponence?

Comment: In topology it comes about  naturally by allowing empty simplices and making the boundary of a 0-simplex empty.

Comment: Do you have any particular motivation to not use augmented complexes?

Comment: Some years ago someone asked in this site why people like reduced (co)homologies. The answers there probable can illuminate the reason for using augmented complexes.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: That looks like a reasonable motivation i was looking for, thanks! So as far as I understand your point correctly, consequently the advantage is then that this provides seemingly the kind of ' uniformity' in the sense that arguments using induction on degree of the chain starting at $ 0$ circumvent treating more sometimes annoying exceptional cases when we add artificially this 'auxilary' -1-simplex aka the 'empty' simplex as generator of -1 piece? Is that the crucial point in the story?

Comment: Yes. For instance notice if you try to define the relative homology of a pair since the empty simplex belongs to the subspace you get the usual relative homology.  And this explains why you have the long exact sequence of relative homology groups

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: for sake of completeness here another example I found where Allen Hatcher gave in his AT book (page 121 in the online available source) a concrete situation where it might be "convenient" to make use of this passing to augmented complex procedure to make a proof more "handy" - or say amenable